# Error in broadcast receiver for android, it listens to all SMSs that my phone receives

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm doing an encryption SMS app, in which, user can encrypt the text and send SMS through my apps.
I used the following broadcast receiver.
The problem is that its listen to all the SMS that come to my phone.
How to make it so that it will only listen to the SMS sent from my apps? Other sms's should open as normal, using default SMS application

```
public class SmsBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

 // Specify the bundle to get object based on SMS protocol "pdus"
 Object[] object = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
 SmsMessage sms[] = new SmsMessage[object.length]; 
 Intent in=new Intent(context,DisplaySMSActivity.class);
 in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 String msgContent = "";
 String originNum = "";
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

 for (int i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {

 sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) object[i]);

 // get the received SMS content
 msgContent = sms[i].getDisplayMessageBody();

 //get the sender phone number
 originNum = sms[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

 //aggregate the messages together when long message are fragmented
 sb.append(msgContent);

 //abort broadcast to cellphone inbox
 abortBroadcast();

 }

 //fill the sender's phone number into Intent
 in.putExtra("originNum", originNum);

 //fill the entire message body into Intent
 in.putExtra("msgContent", new String(sb));

 //start the DisplaySMSActivity.java
 context.startActivity(in);

 }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..can u give me some reference link..it will be more helpful..thanks MR.Loofer..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not correctly registering your receiver.

When declaring a Receiver in the manifest (or programmatically), you can also specify an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html). You can specify the 'action' you want to receive in your receiver.

For example: "com.your_app_package.sms_encrypted_msg".

Either way, remember to check the action in the `onReceive` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if(intent.getAction().equals('com.your_app_package.sms_encrypted_msg')){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: are you also setting the `setPackage()` in the intent you are sending? I know that starting from Ice Cream Sandwich, there is more control on this. and this worked out for me in an app I was working on. [Look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter))